# How to ignore subclasses in hibernate entities when persisting

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have a simple entity class like this

```
@Entity
public class Car{
   @Column protected String name;
}
```

Everything is ok but now I want to use subclasses or anonymous classes of this entity.

```
public class TestCar extends Car{
    TestCar(){ this.name = "Test"; }
}
```

or

```
void foo(){
   Car c = new Car(){
             { this.name = "Lone"; }
           };
   // ...
}
```

These subclasses are just for instantiation purposes and can be ignored completely by hibernate.

But when I try to save the entity I get an "Unknown entity"-Exception.

Is there a way that hibernate ignores such subclasses?

Edit: *It would be nice if we could find an answer to the question. It is not helpful (at least not for me) to discuss all the other (well known) pattern. You should see that this is only a strongly simplified example to clarify the problem. (Probably you should just ignore the use-cases)*

Just found this possible duplicate (also no solution): [How to persist an entity from an non-entity subclass in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467704)

Comment: You could try to cast it to superclass, but i doubt it will work - just never tested it.
Why cant you simply create `Car` insteed of subclassing it?

Comment: Casting doesn't work. My only solution is to make a full copy of all attributes into a new "plain" car object but this is very unhandy.

Comment: That is what I have mentioned. Create factory method for that and it will become handy and simple.

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to work.

IMHO you should rethink your design. Is realy TestCar or anonymous Car class a subtype of Car? I think you are using wrong tool for creating instances. You can use Builder pattern.